# in Xcode, how does the delegating object know WHICH method on the delegate object to call?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, delegates

For instance, I have a view controller that conforms to a UITextFieldDelegate protocol and inherits a method from that protocol..

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
                   replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        // do some stuff...
        return true
    }
```

In the main.storyboard file, I control-dragged the textfield to this view controller, and clicked 'delegate' to let the project know that my view controller is now the delegate for this text field.

Now... I understand that this view controller is now referred to in my UITextField under the property called "delegate", but in my view controller, I have multiple methods and properties in my text field.

How did the text field know to be passed in as the first argument in the textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString) function? As opposed to any of the other random, unrelated functions?

Thanks

**Bonus Related Question**
In my view controller (the delegate of the UITextField), there is an @IBAction target function whose source is the same text field input object. Now... I have functionality in that IBAction function to basically print to the screen the contents of the input UPON edit of the input's value.

However, with this new delegate function, I have implemented some functionality to NOT change the input's value if there are two of the same characters. When I run my app, I can see that because the delegate functionality is working, when two of the same numbers are in the text field, the value does not update in the text field, and therefore, the @IBAction function is not even called (or at least, nothing gets printed to the console).

This suggests, to me, that the delegate function has precedence over the @IBAction function.

Simply looking for a true or false answer on that observation. Thanks!

Comment: Your text field will call the delegate methods it has to call ( so it can be all of them ). Each method has a different purpose. If you only need to use `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString)`, then you can implement this delegate method only.

Comment: And if you want to start implementing Apple stuff ( iOS, macOS, tvOS etc... ) you must learn a bit more about [delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) as it is an essential patern used in these technologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `UITextField` will be code equivalent to:

```
self.delegate?.textfield(self, shouldChangeCharactersIn: rangeThatChanged, replacementString: stringThatChanged)
```

So, the text field code calls the specific function on its delegate, passing the required parameters including a reference to itself.  This is no different to invoking any function on an object reference.

In respect of your 'Bonus question', the name of the delegate function is *should*ChangeCharactersIn. This function indicates whether the change takes place by returning true or false.  If it returns false then the change is discarded.  If there is no change then the *change* action is not invoked.

Comment: Excellent answer thank you. One more follow up question though - Why use the process of setting an object up as a delegate for another object, when we can just use @IBActions? For instance, I see in IB that I have the option to set up an IBAction from the text field to the view controller called "editing did begin". Then I could create a custom function to do xyz when that is invoked. But there is also a delegate method called "textFieldDidBeginEditing"... Wouldn't these two do the same thing? Only difference being the delegate method was written by Apple and has preset functionality?

Comment: All `@IBAction` functions have the same signature.  Essentially `functionName(sender: UIView)->Void`  An IBAction cannot accept any other arguments and does not return a value.  You would have to ask Apple why there is overlapping functionality between the delegate and actions for a UITextField; personally I suspect that setting a single `delegate` property is simpler than adding multiple action handlers (and still having to set a delegate for the things that can't be action handlers)

Comment: Thanks, I think that sort of answered the question. So there are possibly two reasons why to use a delegate as opposed to IBAction: (1) Some methods that a delegate can perform are not 'actions' per say, they are more like methods that request info. Like the one that stops the input from accepting any characters, which isn't so much an action as a test for values. (2) Using IBActions could get heavy when you start adding multiple action handlers

Comment: Yes, and you might want to pass more values; consider `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` - it has a void return but needs to pass different parameters than an IBAction signature can accept

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield) for this method states:

> The text field calls this method whenever user actions cause its text to change.

So when user actions cause a UITextField's text to change, the UITextField code checks to see whether the UITextField object has a delegate, and, if it does, whether that delegate object implements `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn: replacementString:)`. If it does, UITextField calls the method, passing the UITextField object as the first parameter.